# Selectable/Focusable input field, not writable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, bootstrap-modal

I have a select inside a bootstrap modal but when I show it and call `$('#select_value').select2();` the input field is not writable. It is selectable/focusable but now writable at all...
I initially found some problem with z-index but since it is selectable, I don't think it is an index problem.

This is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="small" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form>
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Select</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <select id='select_value' class="form-control select2me" required>
                                <option></option>
                                <option value='v1'>V1</option>
                                <option value='v2'>V2</option>
                                <option value='v3'>V3</option>
                                <option value='v4'>V4</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn blue btn-save">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

I also tried to change plugin to get teh same result, but I get the same issue...
This is what I tried to use:

[Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) 
[BSelect](https://github.com/gustavohenke/bselect)

Comment: put your code fiddle please

Comment: Well.....apparently seems to work in the fiddle... :\
http://jsfiddle.net/t3nckdfj/

Do you have any idea about what could cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: I solved it. I was using an external plugin to block the UI, and I don't know why, this plugin was blocking the input to any field...

Answer (score 1):

please try to add this script somewhere after bootstrap script

`<script type="text/javascript">
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
 </script>`

or try to remove the `tabindex="-1"` on your modal